# oracle 12c - PDB altered with errors

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, pluggable-database

I have Oracle 12c installed.
I have two schemas installed in the plaggable DB ORCLPDB.
I restarted the machine where both oracle and my application exist.

now when I'm trying to open the pluggable database ORCLPDB using the below query :

```
alter pluggable database orclpdb open;
```

I'm getting the following Warning:

> Warning: PDB altered with errors.

when I run this query :

```
SELECT NAME,STATUS,MESSAGE FROM PDB_PLUG_IN_VIOLATIONS;
```

I get this entry :

```
Name       Status     MESSAGE
--------------------------------
ORCLPDB    PENDING    Sync PDB failed with ORA-65177 during 'ALTER USER user123 IDENTIFIED BY *'
```

where user123 is an essential user that I cannot get rid of.

when I restarted the server , there was a hanged database transaction in the application   , so I'm suspecting that this is the reason why the pluggable database is not opening correctly.

any suggestion to solve this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Hang in transaction will not cause this. By any chance you have the same user created in cdb ROOT and PDB?

Comment: @learningloop no it's only created in PDB.

Comment: These kind of errors requires the user to be dropped, and PDB to be reopened to resolve it. Any chance to use different username?

Comment: @learningloop the PDB contains two users . I dropped the one I'm suspecting to be the issue .Should I delete all the users in the PDB ?